# Integral of Modified Bessel Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

> Evaluate:
>   $$\int\limits_{x=0}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}I_0(x) \ln(I_0(x))x \, dx$$
>
> where $I_0(x)$ is the modified [Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1) and zeroth order, and $\alpha>0$.

I can find upper bounds and lower bounds using the expansion of $I_0(x)$; however, they are not enough. I need an exact value, no bounds.

Comment: A not-so-terrible upper bound can be derived from $\log I_0(x)\leq x$. We have $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} x\cdot I_0(x) e^{-ax^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2a}e^{\frac{1}{4a}}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. The diamond means you are one of the moderators?

Comment: You're welcome, and... yup.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio To get another bound I can use $\ln(x)\leq x-1$.  Then I will need to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}x I_0(x)^2 e^{-a x^2} dx$. Do you have an answer for this as well?

Comment: Such bound is much worse than the previous one, but in any case $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x I_0(x)^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2a} e^{1/(2a)} I_0(1/(2a)).$$

Comment: Lower  bound is $1-\frac{1}{x}\leq \ln (x)$.Then: $$\int_0^{\infty } \exp \left(-\alpha  x^2\right) I_0(x) \left(1-\frac{1}{I_0(x)}\right) x \, dx=\frac{-1+e^{\frac{1}{4 \alpha }}}{2 \alpha }$$

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer, but too long to be edited in the comments section.
$$S(\alpha)=\int\limits_{x=0}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}I_0(x) \ln(I_0(x))x \, dx$$
$$S(\alpha)=\frac12\int\limits_{x=0}^\infty e^{-\alpha x}I_0(\sqrt{x}) \ln(I_0(\sqrt{x})) \, dx$$
In fact $S(\alpha)$ is the Laplace transform of the function $I_0(\sqrt{x}) \ln(I_0(\sqrt{x}))$.
$$S(\alpha)=\mathcal{L}_x\Big(I_0(\sqrt{x}) \ln(I_0(\sqrt{x}))\Big)(\alpha) $$
In the extended tables of Laplace transform (for example from H.Bateman) one find the Laplace transforms of a lot of functions involving combinations of Bessel functions, such as $I_\nu(c_1\sqrt{x}) I_\nu(c_2\sqrt{x}))$ for example. But not the function with logarithm $I_0(\sqrt{x}) \ln(I_0(\sqrt{x}))$.

Also math software such as WolframAlpha find no result in terms of standard mathematical function.

This draw to think that nowadays $S(\alpha)$ cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions. Of course, this is not a definitive proof. Moreover, new special functions might be defined in the future and among them one allowing to express $S(\alpha)$ in closed form.